# Does this TPL idiom exist?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, idioms

Using TPL with .NET 4, I'm trying to decide how to design APIs that deal with futures. One possibility that occurred to me was to mimic the async pattern but without an `End(IAsyncResult)` method:

```
public Task<int> BeginGetAge()
{
    // create and return task
}

public int GetAge()
{
    return this.BeginGetAge().Result;
}
```

As such, callers can decide whether to call the blocking or non-blocking version of `GetAge()`. Moreover, they have access to the future so can construct continuations on top of it etcetera.

Is this idiom valid? Are there any obvious drawbacks or problems that I'm missing? Does it perhaps even have an official name?

Comment: Your second case would benefit greatly from `await` I believe.

Comment: FYI, Stephen Toub has posted about this (offering sync wrappers for async methods) - tl;dr avoid it :)  see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx and also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning a `Task` is the new C#5 async way - it's called the TAP: [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19957).

The only difference is that the method is named `GetAgeAsync`.

So, yes - this approach is recommended as it will make it easy to port to C#5 async when it is released.

Answer (score 2):

This idiom seems perfectly valid to me and indeed support for `Task` based asynchrony will be a big feature in upcoming versions of .Net.

However, I would change your implementation so the blocking method `GetAge` does not call the async method and then wait for it - the overhead in (potentially) creating a new thread is unnecessary.

Comment: One could swap the relationship between the methods and have `BeginGetAge()` return `Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetAge())`.

Comment: Well, I don't think it would create a new thread so much as switch context to an existing thread. And even then, it's up to the scheduler to decide whether this is necessary. But I take your point and Sean's suggestion makes sense.